# Show that $\mathbb{Z} \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I can show that $\mathbb{Z} \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}$ is generated by {$1\bigotimes 1$}. But I could not show that it is linearly independent.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that a module is linearly independent. Do you mean the set $\{1\otimes 1\}$? It's a singleton; just show it's nonzero.

Comment: Yes I meant {${1 \bigotimes 1}$}. How to show that it is non zero?

Comment: To show it is non-zero, it is sufficient to find a bilinear form from $\mathbb Z \otimes \mathbb Z$ to the base ring, most likely $\mathbb Z$ in your case, which takes a non-zero value at $(1 , 1)$.

Comment: Yes. We define $\phi ({a\bigotimes b})=ab$. It is a nonzero bilinear map. we are done Thanks a lot.

Comment: @anomaly In order to show linear independence of the singleton, you need to show that $n(1 \otimes 1) \neq 0$ for all $n \neq 0$. Showing it is nonzero is not enough: consider the singleton $\{1\}$ in the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Joppy: Sure, but the tensor product is clearly torsion-free (e.g., tensor with $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: @jaggu: In case you're unaware, you can use `\otimes` instead of `\bigotimes` to get a symbol that formats better. E.g. you'll get $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z} \bigotimes \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Homomorphisms from $\newcommand{\ot}{\otimes}A\ot B$ to $C$ correspond
to bilinear maps from $A\times B$ to $C$. In more detail, if $\Phi:A\times B\to C$ is bilinear, the corresponding homomorphism $\phi$ satisfies
$\phi(a\ot b)=\Phi(a,b)$. This is the *universal property* of the tensor
product.

Here, define $\Phi:\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}\Z\times\Z\to\Z$ by $\Phi(a,b)=ab$. This is bilinear. The corresponding $\phi:\Z\otimes\Z\to\Z$
has $\phi(a\ot b)=ab$. In particular $\phi(n(1\ot 1))=\phi(n\ot 1)=n$.
If $n\ne 0$ this means that $n(1\ot1)\ne0$. Thus $\{1\ot 1\}$
is a linearly independent set.